# Android 8 Genymotion virtual device freezes at startup

Tags: 16.04, android, genymotion

I use `Ubuntu 16.04` on a machine with `Intel® Core™ i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz × 12` and `8 GiB` RAM. Recently I installed `Genymotion 2.12.1` and created a  `Custom Phone - 8.0 - API 26 - 768x1280` virtual device with `4 processors` and `2048 MB`of RAM. But when I start that device, it freeze at boot. What cause this problem and how I can solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled `nouveau` and installed latest version of my graphics card from NVIDIA. That solves problem completely.